# Grub and easy bcd

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, windows-7

I have installed Windows 7 over Ubuntu 12.04 (on a different partition) and since I have installed Windows 7 as the last step, GRUB did not start and Windows 7 booted automatically.

In order to solve this problem, I had installed EasyBCD and added second partition and everything was okay, but I had 2 GRUB screens.

The first GRUB screen included Windows 7 and Linux Nero Start, and I could have accessed Ubuntu had I chose the Linux Nero Start entry (which included Ubuntu and Windows 7).

In the process of trying to eliminate the other GRUB screen, I deleted the Windows 7 GRUB screen on EasyBCD by accident, and now I cannot boot Windows 7 despite it being visible on GRUB.

If I choose Ubuntu, everything is ok, but if I try to choose the Windows 7 entry, the same GRUB menu screen boots again.

Can you please help me with my problem?

Comment: You can use the `edit` button in order to edit your question. Please put some effort in making your question clear so we can help you. There are sentences like `anit was totallyd the second` that make no sense at all, and were probably just a word you forgot or a missclick. If you edited those it would be of great help.

Answer (score 2):

The Boot Repair program will help you. 
You can find it on: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
That page contains all information you need.
I used it once, when I was running two distros and made the same mistake as you.

Comment: thanks a lot , I just found that app but i couldnt find that app in software Center when i searched it as boot-repair, any suggestion ?